# Composite annotations to reuse

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

we have couple of annotations, for springboot controller method. and these are mostly reused in multiple methods.

```
@Annotation1
@Annotation2
@Annotation3
public void someMethod()
```

combine as

```
@CompositeAnnotation
public void someMethod()
```

Is there a way we can create a composite annotation ? I know we might as well add a new one which encapsulates these, but at times this is not possible.

Just trying to reuse these bunch as single or reduced to fewer ones.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is called _meta-annotation_. Specific tools (such as most of the Spring tools) support it, but it's not a general feature in Java. (Groovy has annotation collectors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to create a new annotation that will have all yours.

You can take a look at `@SpringBootApplication` realization - it contains `@SpringBootConfiguration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` annotations on self, so all of them are applied when  `@SpringBootApplication` is used.

Or `@RestController` which combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

In your case:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Annotation1
@Annotation2
@Annotation3
public @interface CompositeAnnotation
```

Here is some tutorial: https://chrysanthium.com/spring-annotation-composition

Comment: shouldnt it be @Target(ElementType.METHOD)?

Comment: Yep, Method, sorry I thought that you are assigning it to controller class, not method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5730762/alexander-terekhov i did mention the method :) anyway this helps